# How to show distribution $T$ is a constant

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

> Let $T$ be a distribution on $\mathbb{R}$. $\tau_a\phi(x)=\phi(x-a)$ and $\langle T,\tau_a\phi\rangle=\langle T,\phi\rangle$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and all test functions $\phi$. Prove that $T$ is a constant.

I have no idea to prove $\langle T,\phi\rangle=0,$ for all $\phi$.

Comment: My proof strategy would be $(T\ast\phi)(a)=(T\ast\phi)(0)$ for all $a$, hence $T\ast\phi = \text{const}$. So $T'\ast\phi=0$ for all $\phi$, hence $T'=0$ and so finally $T=\text{const}$.

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the question: you are not asked to show that $T$, as a linear functional mapping from $C^\infty_c \to \mathbb{R}$, is constant (if so it would have to be the zero functional, and that certainly need not be true).  Rather, the goal is to show that $T$ corresponds to a constant function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  In other words, show that there exists $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $\phi \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$, we have $\langle T, \phi \rangle = \int_{\mathbb{R}} c \phi(x)\,dx$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in my comment, the goal is to show that there is a constant $c$ such that $\langle T, \phi \rangle = c \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\,dx$ for all test functions $\phi$.

First of all, let's identify the constant $c$.  Let $\psi$ be your favorite test function having $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi(x)\,dx = 1$ and set $c := \langle T, \psi \rangle$.

Next: for any test function $\phi$, show that as $a \to 0$, we have $\frac1a (\phi - \tau_a \phi) \to \phi'$ in the usual topology of $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})$.

Now our hypotheses imply that for any $\phi$,
$$\left\langle T , \frac{1}{a} (\phi - \tau_a \phi) \right\rangle = 0.$$
Since $T$ is a continuous linear functional, we can pass to the limit to conclude $\langle T, \phi' \rangle = 0$.  That means that $T' = 0$ which intuitively should mean that $T$ is constant.

To prove this, let $\phi$ be any test function and set $f(x) = \phi(x) -  \psi(x) \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(t)\,dt$, so that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = 0$.  Therefore, if we set $g(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x f(t)\,dt$, you can verify that $g$ is smooth and compactly supported, and by the fundamental theorem of calculus, $g' = f$.  As such, 
$$0 = \langle T, g' \rangle = \langle T, f \rangle = \langle T, \phi \rangle - c \int_{-\infty}^\infty \phi(x)\,dx$$
which is the desired conclusion.

(The key in the last paragraph is that a test function $f$ is the derivative of another test function iff we have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx = 0$.)